# How to generate 2d numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, generator

I'm trying to generate a 2d numpy array with the help of generators:

```
x = [[f(a) for a in g(b)] for b in c]
```

And if I try to do something like this:

```
x = np.array([np.array([f(a) for a in g(b)]) for b in c])
```

I, as expected, get a np.array of np.array. But I want not this, but ndarray, so I can get, for example, column in a way like this:

```
y = x[:, 1]
```

So, I'm curious whether there is a way to generate it in such a way.

Of course it is possible with creating npdarray of required size and filling it with required values, but I want a way to do so in a line of code.

Comment: And it has to be a generator expression? It can't be a `np.shape` or anything like that?

Comment: what do `f(a)` and `g(b)` do exactly? If they produce numbers, your code should work: that is the correct way to initialize a 2d numpy array (numpy is generally smart enough to cast an array of an array to a ndarray)

Comment: What is `data['Name']` like?  It's best if you give us examples that we can plug and run.  What is the shape of `np._names`?  I don't see any generators in your code, just list comprehensions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This works:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
nd_a = np.array(a)
```

So this should work too:

```
nd_a = np.array([[x for x in y] for y in a])
```

Answer (score 9):

To create a new array, it seems [`numpy.zeros`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) is the way to go

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros(shape=(x, y))
```

You can also set a datatype to allocate it sensibly

```py
>>> np.zeros(shape=(5,2), dtype=np.uint8)
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
>>> np.zeros(shape=(5,2), dtype="datetime64[ns]")
array([['1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000000'],
       ['1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000000'],
       ['1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000000'],
       ['1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000000'],
       ['1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000000']],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

See also

- [How do I create an empty array/matrix in NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568962/how-do-i-create-an-empty-array-matrix-in-numpy)
- [np.full(size, 0) vs. np.zeros(size) vs. np.empty()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213199/np-fullsize-0-vs-np-zerossize-vs-np-empty)

Answer (score 3):

Its very simple, do like this

```
import numpy as np

arr=np.arange(50)
arr_2d=arr.reshape(10,5)    #Reshapes 1d array in to 2d, containing 10 rows and 5 columns.
print(arr_2d)
```