# Speed of np.empty vs np.zeros

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I am using numpy version 1.14.3 and python 2.7.12.

Referencing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213199/np-fullsize-0-vs-np-zerossize-vs-np-empty) question, I am finding dramatically different speeds between initializing arrays with np.zeros and np.empty.  However, the output is the same.

```
import numpy as np
r = np.random.random((50, 100, 100))
z = np.zeros(r.shape)
e = np.empty(r.shape)
np.allclose(e, z)
```

This returns `True`.  However, the timing functions `%timeit` gives very different results:

```
%timeit z = np.zeros(r.shape)
```

> 10000 loops, best of 3: 143 µs per loop

```
%timeit e = np.empty(r.shape)
```

> 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.83 µs per loop

The previously accepted answer referenced above says that `np.zeros` was always the better choice, and that it is faster too.

**Why not use np.empty when it is 80 times faster than np.zeros and returns the same answer?**

**Edit**
As user2285236 pointed out, flipping the order of initializing `z` and `e` will break the equality, because it overwrites on the same memory area.

Comment: There is no guarantee that `np.empty` will return an array full of zeros.

Comment: Also, if you take a closer look at the question you linked, you'll find that the questioner understood this and manually zeroed the `np.empty` return value.

Comment: Yes, I understand, and in previous versions of numpy it was necessary to zero out the array.  Now, it appears to return zeros by default.  Has something changed?

Comment: I think you get zeros because you call np.empty just after `z = np.zeros(r.shape)`. Flip the order and you no longer get True for np.allclose.

Comment: user2285236 is correct.  Flipping the order screws things up.  I will edit the post to reflect this insight.

Comment: For me, I get more zeroes as I increase the size of the array: (2,3,5) has none, (5, 100, 100) has some non-zero values as the start, and (50, 100, 100) is all zero.  Which is fine, because np.empty never promised the results _wouldn't_ be zero-- we're just measuring what junk happened to be in memory beforehand.  If we were bored enough I guess we could look at the memory allocation patterns, but honestly, once we see that it's not guaranteed to be zero we know what we need to _do_ and the rest doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`np.empty` and `np.zeros` do different things.

`np.empty` creates an array from available memory space, leaving whatever values happened to be hanging around in memory as the values.  **These values may or may not be zeros.**

`np.zeros` creates an array from available memory space, and then fills it with zeros for your chosen dtype. Obviously `np.zeros` has to do more work so it should be slower, since it's also writing to the memory allocated.

A more fair comparison would be between `np.empty` and `np.ndarray`.