# Why is np.zeros() faster than re-initializing an existing array in Numba with Python?

Tags: python, numpy, dynamic-memory-allocation, numba, calloc

Why is`numpy.zeros()` faster than re-initializing an existing array?

I work with computer modeling and use numba for my work. Sometimes it is necessary to have a zeroed array to accumulate the results of some operation. In general, I suppose that zeroing an already allocated array cannot be slower than creating a new array filled with zeros, but it is not.  I know about lazy selection (for example [Why is the speed difference between Python's Numpy zeros and empty functions gone for larger array sizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58076522/why-is-the-speed-difference-between-pythons-numpy-zeros-and-empty-functions-gon;) https://vorpus.org/blog/why-does-calloc-exist/), but it must take time to make it zeroed.

As far as I know, `np.zeros` use `calloc` and all acceleration comes from this call and should be reproducible for other languages.
Any guarantees, that's always the case?
It the good practices or not?

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import benchit
nb.set_num_threads(1)

@nb.njit
def numba_operation(in_arr, out):
    for i in range(out.shape[0]):
        for j in range(out.shape[1]):
            out[i,j] += in_arr[i,j] * 2 + 4
            
@nb.njit
def numba_operation_with_zeros(in_arr, out):
    for i in range(out.shape[0]):
        for j in range(out.shape[1]):
            out[i,j] = 0
    for i in range(out.shape[0]):
        for j in range(out.shape[1]):
            out[i,j] += in_arr[i,j] * 2 + 4

    
def every_time_generate_zeros(data):
    in_arr, out = data
    out = np.zeros(shape=(out.shape[0], out.shape[0]))
    numba_operation(in_arr, out)
    return out

def make_zeros_numba(data):
    in_arr, out = data
    numba_operation_with_zeros(in_arr, out)

def generate_arrays(n):
    in_arr = np.random.rand(2**n, 2**n)
    out = np.random.rand(2**n, 2**n)
    return in_arr, out

t = benchit.timings([every_time_generate_zeros, make_zeros_numba], 
                    {n:generate_arrays(n) for n in np.arange(9, 15, 1)}, 
                    input_name='2^n')
t.plot(modules=benchit.extract_modules_from_globals(globals()))
```

Results:

[image: code output]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR:** the observed behaviour is due to a combination of several low-level effects related to CPU caches and virtual memory.

---

For large arrays, `np.zeros` does not actually fill anything in physical memory on mainstream platforms. In this case, the `calloc` system call is used internally to reserve a zeroized memory space from the Operating System (OS). This memory space is **virtually allocated**, not physically. Virtual memory is split in small chunks called pages. Allocated pages are **only filled during first touch** on mainstream OS. Note that `malloc` (called by `np.empty`) also zeroize memory for sake of security (since no information should leak from one application to another).

What this means is that `np.zeros` is cheap for large arrays (because of the lazy/deferred initialization) compared to manually filling arrays with zeros (much slower on mainstream OS). If you write into a newly allocated array, like in `every_time_generate_zeros`, pages needs to be zeroized. However, **zeroing memory is performed on the fly, page per page**. This is a huge difference with the `make_zeros_numba` implementation which first zeroize the whole array and then fill it again with non-zero values! Indeed, classical pages are typically few KiB wide (4 KiB on mainstream x86-64 platforms) so they can fit in the **L1 CPU cache**. When `every_time_generate_zeros` write a value in a virtually allocated page not yet filled with zeros, a **page fault** is triggered and the processor fills the whole page with zeros. The zeroized page is then in the cache so writing in it is much faster. This is why `make_zeros_numba` is slower in your case : the array needs to be stored to the DRAM twice because it likely do not fit in the (same) CPU cache (at least, not for `n >= 2^12`).

What happens under the hood is pretty complex. In fact, there are few missing details making this even more complex, but I tried to make the explantation relatively simple to be quite easy to understand so far.

---

If you want something fast, then you need to virtually split the array in chunks (ie. tile) filled/computed on the fly and also avoid creating temporary arrays. However, this is hard to do in non-trivial codes (in fact, not always possible). This is critical for performance because of the [Memory Wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory#Memory_wall).

---

### Additional notes and explanation

Note that page faults are also expensive. In fact they can be more expensive than reusing the same array on some system (typically servers having a big DRAM bandwidth). As a result, there are computing machine where `make_zeros_numba` can actually be faster! The behaviour is also dependent of the operating system and the standard C library implementation.

Using multiple threads to fill the target arrays also often impact performance of the two approach differently. Indeed, page faults can barely scale on some system (eg. Windows) while they can scale well on some others (eg. Linux). In general, DRAM writes do not scale with the number of core : only few cores are enough on most machines to saturate the DRAM bandwidth.

I deliberately not mentioned an important factor when it comes to filling memory with zeros. Modern x86-64 processors use a write-back CPU caches. This means data needs to be read from the DRAM for a *cache-line* to be written (possibly many times). The modified cache-lines are then written back later to the DRAM (typically during cache-misses). Reading DRAM to write zeros is inefficient (half the bandwidth is wasted). This is why modern x86-64 processors also have dedicated instruction to avoid this problem : non-temporal stores (NT-stores). The `memcpy` (and possibly `memset`) system calls generally use them when needed. NT-stores are only worth it for large arrays not fitting in RAM or ones that are never directly re-used (the later very hard to know in practice). Indeed, small arrays tends to fit in CPU caches so they do not need to be stored over and over to DRAM (much slower than CPU caches) This is why small array can behave very differently than large ones. Recent modern x86-64 processors even have special instructions to fill memory with zeros faster than usual instructions.

Note that there are also *huge pages* which are much bigger than classical pages (eg. 2 MiB) so to reduce the overhead of the small classical pages (especially page faults). Using them can strongly impact performance since the L1 cache is generally sufficiently large to hold 1 huge page. In fact, this is often true for the L2 (if any). The LLC cache tends to be large enough, but it is also significantly slower than the L1/L2. Besides, huge pages can be [automatically used by the OS](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/mm/transhuge.html).

Finally, note that the Numba JIT can be clever enough to replace the zeroing loop with a `memset` which can be significantly faster because of NT-store. However, it turns out this is [platform dependent](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/7534) so far.

---

Additional related posts:

- [How is memory handled once touched for the first time in numpy.zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70055063/how-is-memory-handled-once-touched-for-the-first-time-in-numpy-zeros/70056188#70056188)
- [Why is Numpy much faster at creating a Zero array compared to replacing the values of an existing array with zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67270937/why-is-numpy-much-faster-at-creating-a-zero-array-compared-to-replacing-the-valu/67271140#67271140)

Comment: Is there any reason why this code might produce different results on different runs on the same machine?  I'm starting this again today, and `every_time_generation_of_zeros` is slower, but after some runs this function become faster again.

Comment: This is pretty unusual and certainly require an investigation. This can happen on NUMA machines for example (eg. typically on servers, or PC with AMD processors). On Linux, you can control the NUMA allocation policy with `numactl`. Besides, the speed of allocations and page faults can be slightly impacted by the state of the OS (how much memory is use, its fragmentation, etc.) though I do not expect this to be the cause unless you run in a pathological case.

Comment: There are few other possible explanations. Fun fact : on one of my old machine, I had a non-uniform DRAM configuration (eg. 4 GiB + 2 GiB), so the pages was not balanced between the 2 DRAM channels and the processor was also not able to interleave accesses (although interleaving is very common) resulting in weird benchmark results changing chaotically. In fact, the memory throughput was often changing when my PC was put in sleep mode just before.